# Why/how did mjølnir do what it did in Thor 4?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love and Thunder*, Mjølnir

> reassembles itself for Jane. Exactly why is hard to tell. The movie implies that it did so because Thor accidently programs it with the purpose to protect her, however, this scene may instead be explaining how Jane was able to wield it at all (thus meaning she wasn't worthy in Odin's eyes).

If it gained the ability of reassembly because of Thor's reprogramming, then the question of why Odin didn't give it that ability to begin with arises. If it already had the reassembly ability, then the question of why it didn't reassemble earlier arises.

So, why/how did this happen?

Comment: It reassembled because Thor enchanted it to protect her at all costs. The initial enchantment was just about worthiness, presumably Odin didn't really consider the need for it being reassembled and that wasn't the point of the enchantment anyway.

Comment: Mjolnir is basically sentient - https://screenrant.com/thor-love-thunder-mjolnir-return-explained/

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I considered that. However, Odin isn't that short-sighted. He has a degree of omiscience. Surely he'd know, or at least be able to predict, that Hela (or any other superstrong foe of Thor's), could destroy the hammer. He knew for a fact that Hela would return after his death. So, more likely, if it didn't have the reassembly function to begin with, it's because Odin didn't want it to. Not because he didn't consider it, but because he did consider it, and decided against it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, but what is the relevance?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137709/discussion-on-question-by-user110391-why-how-did-mjolnir-do-what-it-did-in-thor).